# How to force ALSA output as single-channel?

Tags: arch-linux, alsa

My speakers are broken and play at different loudness from time to time. This means that the off-center parts of music sound wrong. How can I force all sound to be centered, so that the two speakers have the same output?

I'm using ALSA.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://superuser.com/q/155522/102592) at superuser.com help?

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the volume of the two speakers independently by adjusting the balance.  An application like `alsamixer` or `gnome-alsamixer` or `alsamixergui` will let you do it graphically, or you can use the `amixer` command-line tool:

```
amixer sset Master 70%,30%
```

This would shift the balance to the left.